# NPM error when installing blessed-contrib: 'types/blessed' is not in the npm registry

Tags: node.js, raspbian-lite

I'm running Raspbian Jessie Lite and having trouble getting [`blessed-contrib`](https://github.com/yaronn/blessed-contrib) running.

`npm install` gives me the following errors:

```
pi@PAPI:~/blessed-contrib $ npm install
npm ERR! 404 Not Found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 'types/blessed' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it
npm ERR! 404 It was specified as a dependency of 'blessed-contrib'
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, or http url, or git url.

npm ERR! System Linux 4.9.41+
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /home/pi/blessed-contrib
npm ERR! node -v v4.8.2
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.21
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/pi/blessed-contrib/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I've already looked at [Getting NPM installed on Raspberry Pi (Wheezy Image)](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4194/getting-npm-installed-on-raspberry-pi-wheezy-image) but none of the provided solutions work.

Comment: Could you try running `sudo npm install -g npm` and then repeat `npm install`? I *suspect* the issue is that your npm version is too old, but can't confirm it myself.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your version of npm is too old to support scoped packages which blessed-contrib is making use of. But it is only using it for a dev dependency. You can try doing a production install to skip it with

```
npm install --production
```

Or alternatively upgrade npm to a later version.

```
npm install --global npm
```

and run it with the absolute path like

```
/usr/local/bin/npm install
```